# How to restart shiny server in Docker container?

Tags: r, shell, docker, shiny, shiny-server

I have a Dockerized R Shiny app that extends the [rocker/shiny](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny/) image. I would like to restart the shiny-server inside of the Docker container at some point. From the [documentation of shiny-server](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#stopping-and-starting), I tried all the commands for different Linux builds and none of them worked.

Does anyone know how to restart the shiny-server in the Docker container?

Comment: Restart the container?

Comment: Docker container manage one process inside himself. If this process is shutting down container will be shutting down too. Therefore if you want to shutdown container you need to shutdown your application. But you need to starting up it outside of docker.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I managed to restart the Docker container from inside of it by hitting the API endpoint of marathon that runs it to walk around this problem.

Comment: @ZichenWang can you please share your solution? I'm having the same problem ATM

Comment: Restarting the container would destroy all hot changes you made to the container. Normally that's a good thing, you shouldn't really be making those kinds of changes. But sometimes you need to debug a deployed container, because the problem doesn't occur on your local system. You don't really want to redeploy the whole app for every single debugging change. In this scenario, it'd be nice to be able to debug straight in the deployed (to lower environments, obviously) container, and only redeploy after you are sure of the problem. would be helpful to restart the whole app but not the container.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
docker ps
```

lists all running containers, get the required container id. Then run

```
docker exec -it <container_id> bash
```

to get into the required docker container. Then

```
sudo -i 
sudo systemctl restart shiny-server
```

to restart the shiny server. Hope that helps, systemctl will probably only work on Ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately rocker/shiny has no systemctl in it. If you check their entry point (https://github.com/rocker-org/shiny/blob/master/shiny-server.sh), shine runs as a simple app, not a service

Answer (score 1):

An app running in shiny server can be restarted by updating the timestamp on a file `restart.txt`.

From the docs:

> An application can be restarted by altering the "modified time" on a
> file named `restart.txt` in the application's directory. This can most
> easily be done using the `touch` utility, as in `touch restart.txt`, which
> will update the modified timestamp on this file to the current time.
> Upon the next new connection to the application, Shiny Server will
> spawn a new R process to run the "new" (restarted) Shiny Application
> for this and future users.

(Source: https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#restarting-an-application)

If you need to *periodically* restart the application (eg. if you set `app_idle_timeout = 0` but wish to regularly restart to pull some updated data), you could use a cronjob in the `rocker/shiny` container to `touch restart.txt` according to some desired schedule.